# JavaFX 13 throwing java.lang.ClassCastException when click on TableView

Tags: java, javafx, classcastexception

I'm trying update a form when a table row is clicked. Usually the error happen in the first click, but updates the form properly.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.javafx.geom.BoxBounds cannot be cast to class com.sun.javafx.geom.RectBounds (com.sun.javafx.geom.BoxBounds and com.sun.javafx.geom.RectBounds are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @5419f379)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.applyTransform(NGNode.java:2484)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateGroupDirtyRegion(NGNode.java:1226)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateDirtyRegions(NGNode.java:1041)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateGroupDirtyRegion(NGNode.java:1208)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateDirtyRegions(NGNode.java:1041)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateGroupDirtyRegion(NGNode.java:1208)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateDirtyRegions(NGNode.java:1041)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateGroupDirtyRegion(NGNode.java:1208)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateDirtyRegions(NGNode.java:1041)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateGroupDirtyRegion(NGNode.java:1208)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateDirtyRegions(NGNode.java:1041)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateGroupDirtyRegion(NGNode.java:1208)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateDirtyRegions(NGNode.java:1041)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateGroupDirtyRegion(NGNode.java:1208)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateDirtyRegions(NGNode.java:1041)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateGroupDirtyRegion(NGNode.java:1208)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateDirtyRegions(NGNode.java:1041)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateGroupDirtyRegion(NGNode.java:1208)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.accumulateDirtyRegions(NGNode.java:1041)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:248)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I was using Java 11 (OpenJDK) and JavaFx 2, then I found some answers that it could be some incompatibilty, then I moved to JavaFx 13, but the problem is still happening. If I stop the code in the event method onMouseClicked() the error doesn't happen, however if pass the mouse over the table is enough to throw it.

```
 equipmentTableView.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
    if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
        int index = equipmentTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        equipment = equipmentTableView.getItems().get(index);

        loadData(equipment);
    }
});
```

```xml
<TableView layoutX="20.0" layoutY="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="450.0" fx:id="equipmentTableView">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" text="Nome" fx:id="nameColumn">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="name"/></cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" text="I.P." fx:id="ipColumn">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="ipAddress"/></cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="160.0" text="Serial" fx:id="dicomEquipmentIdColumn">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="dicomEquipmentId"/></cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="100.0" text="Sala" fx:id="roomNickNameColumn">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="roomId"/></cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
    <effect>
        <InnerShadow/>
    </effect>
</TableView>
```

I'm using Springboot 2.2 with FXMLloader defined in the class:

```
public class SpringFXMLLoader {
    private final ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
    private final ApplicationContext context;

    public SpringFXMLLoader(ResourceBundle resourceBundle, ApplicationContext context) {
        this.resourceBundle = resourceBundle;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Parent load(String fxmlPath) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = getFxmlLoader(fxmlPath);

        return loader.load();
    }

    public Pane loadPane(String fxmlPath) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = getFxmlLoader(fxmlPath);

        return loader.load();
    }

    private FXMLLoader getFxmlLoader(String fxmlPath) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        loader.setResources(resourceBundle);
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
        return loader;
    }

}
```

Any help is welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was the problem, however it was solved by moving the table declaration from FXML file to the controller in initialize().

Comment: most probably not _solved_ but smeared over ;) Sounds like the field/s are not injected as expected. In your shoes I would do my very best to understand and fix the real reason, otherwise you'll be producing brittle code with time bombs.